# Vue.JS SSR how to use with vue router?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've read the documentation about SSR.
But, I can't get it to work. (I don't know what to do).

I generated the project with vue cli, vue new frontend.
I selected typescript, and all configs in package.json. I am using the Vue router. 
In all tutorials I've read, I see everybody does use Express. But I don't want to. How can I make vue router render my pages with ssr renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Nuxt.js instead of Vue CLI.
And then you generate static pages at the end